# Mysql select query where multiple row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select `post_id` where (meta_key = group_name and meta_value = Caucaia) and (meta_key = _featured and meta_value = 1)

Table: `wp_postmeta`

```
post_id | meta_key | meta_value
---------------------------
746     | group_name | Caucaia
746     | _featured  | 1
747     | group_name | Caucaia
747     | _featured  | 0
1791    | group_name | Aruba
1791    | _featured  | 1
```

I tried the below query but doesn't works

```
SELECT `post_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE (`meta_key` = 'group_name' and `meta_value` ='Caucaia' and `post_id` in (746, 747, 731, 1791, 1799)) or (`meta_key` = '_featured' and `meta_value` ='1' and `post_id` in (746, 747, 731, 1791, 1799)) GROUP BY `post_id`
```

How do I make query to select from multiple row? or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT `post_id`
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE (`meta_key` = 'group_name' and `meta_value` ='Caucaia' and `post_id` in (746, 747, 731, 1791, 1799)) or
      (`meta_key` = '_featured' and `meta_value` ='1' and `post_id` in (746, 747, 731, 1791, 1799))
GROUP BY `post_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Actually, I notice the two lists are the same.  I would write this using list constructors:

```
SELECT `post_id`
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE (post_id` in (746, 747, 731, 1791, 1799)) AND
      (meta_key, meta_value) IN (('group_name', 'Caucaia'), ('_featured', '1'))
GROUP BY `post_id`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once way to do this is to have a `where` clause with all the combinations you need, and count the number of rows it returns:

```
SELECT   post_id
FROM     wp_postmeta
WHERE    (meta_key = 'group_name' AND meta_value = 'Caucaia') OR 
         (meta_key = '_featured' AND meta_value = '1')
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: did you forget the `IN` section?